# listview.getfirstvisibleposition() and getlastvisibleposition() returning wrong values

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a listview in one of my activities. I want to know how many items are visible to user currently. So I tried `listview.getfirstvisibleposition` and `listview.getlastvisibleposition`. But they are returning -1 and 0 respectively.

Below is my relevant code.

```
listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
//fill arrayList
listView.setAdapter(newProductAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.activity_product_adapter, arrayList));
Log.d("first",String.valueOf(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()));
Log.d("last",String.valueOf(listView.getLastVisiblePosition()));
```

Result of first log is -1 and second is 0.
Whereas in my device there are 4 items are displayed in listview.
What went wrong here?

Comment: You are showing only Log in your question, also post how have you used it in you code

Comment: For getFirstVisiblePosition(), you need to do this in your Adapter, perhaps in getView().

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be because you are using these methods just right after the `setAdapter()` method.

There is always a time required to inflate the list items and before the inflation is complete you might get wrong results.

You should do it on a particular event like a click of a `Button` (`OnClickListener`) or `onScroll` (`OnScrollListenr`) of the `ListView`.

---

**[EDIT]** For you queries in comments, you can override your `Activity`'s  [**`onPostResume`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPostResume()) method and there you can use the `getfirstvisibleposition` & `getlastvisibleposition` methods:

> Called when activity resume is complete (after `onResume()` has been called). Applications will generally not implement this method; it is intended for system classes to do final setup after application resume code has run.
>
> *Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.*

Comment: I think you're right. But then how do i know how many rows are displayed when first time layout is inflated? . I mean there will be no scroll event just after layout is inflated and listview is set. I hope I'm clear with my question

Comment: @Apsaliya `ListView.getChildCount()` is what you are looking for. Sorry I am still not getting what you are tring to achieve.

Comment: When activity is created, listview layout will be inflated. There will be some items visible at that time. How do i find that some? Afterward when user scrolls, I can use those methods(getfirstvisibleposition)  via scroll event as you pointed out earlier. But what about very first time? I hope I'm clear now.

Comment: @Apsaliya see the updated answer. I am sure this is what you need. Please upvote if it helps `:)`

Comment: I agree with SMR post, need to do it in an event method. If you do that, then you may not need getFirstVisiblePosition() since the listener should pass the position, and you can get the number of items in a listview.